# How can I use Unicode (or just Cyrillic) chars on TStringField.FieldName property on Delphi?

Tags: delphi, unicode, tclientdataset, tfield, tstringfield

How can I use Unicode (or just Cyrillic) chars on `TStringField.FieldName` property of `TClientDataSet` on Delphi?

I've tried this and it doesn't work on the last line:

```
aStringField := TStringField.Create(aClientDataSet);
aStringField.FieldName := 'аАяЯ';
aStringField.DataSet := aClientDataSet;
aClientDataSet.CreateDataset;
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't convey anything.  What error message do you get?

Comment: Error: Field not found. English `FileName` works fine.

Comment: People usually use English names for columns.

Comment: I need to use Cyrillyc.

Comment: Well, I would understand it for `DisplayLabel`, but for the `FieldName` it's more than weird. It's a client dataset that you seem to build right now. Why do you have this requirement ?

Comment: Do you know whether your Midas.Dll supports Cyrillic in field names?  Also, is this CDS free-standing or is it linked to a database backend via a TProvider?

Comment: I need to generate XML with data and column captions using TClientDataSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program below compiles and executes (XE4) without error.

```
program CDS;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, db, dbclient;

procedure Test;
var
  aClientDataSet : TClientDataSet;
  aStringField : TStringField;
begin
  aClientDataSet := TClientDataSet.Create(Nil);
  aStringField := TStringField.Create(aClientDataSet);
  aStringField.FieldName := 'аАяЯ';
  aStringField.DataSet := aClientDataSet;
  aClientDataSet.CreateDataset;
end;

begin
  Test;
end.
```

Otoh if I use your declaration of aStringField (i.e. as TField) and your method of creating it, I get the r/time error "Invalid field type" on aClientDataSet.CreateDataset.

Comment: I've used TStringField and got error "Field not found". The question was simplified.

Comment: Well, it works for me, like I said.  What Delphi version are you using?  Did you try running what I posted?

Comment: Delphi XE5. Didn't try your code yet but it looks similar to mine.

Comment: Also, you aren't showing all the properties of your TClientDataSet, so:  do you have any FieldDefs defined on it.

Comment: No, I haven't: `aClientDataSet := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);`

Comment: Well, the program in my answer boils what you posted down to a SSCCE, and that produces no error.  If it doesn't work for you, which you still haven't said, then presumably the problem must be some difference between XE4 and XE5; if otoh it does, but your code still doesn't work, it must be because of something you're not showing us.

Comment: Your program works fine. But my code is exactly the same but on the big project.

Comment: Happy hunting then!  I obviously can't help you any more.

Comment: I've found out the error raises with many fields. (One field works fine on the project too.)

Comment: Then make a SSCCE with the second field and QC it.